# Access Apex Rest API as Customer Community User

Tags: apex, community, soap-api, callout, apexrest

Can I access Apex Rest API from an external system using customer community user credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this below link helps in your scenario.

The great Pat Patterson has a blog post about this on the developer relations blog (https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/02/oauth-for-portal-users.html) which gives some details about setting this up.

Check this as well.

(https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en_US))

Comment: @metadaddy, aka the great Pat Patterson! (I found that answer to be a great help as well!!)

Comment: @Samuel Robert, Am getting unsupported_granttype error.

Comment: I tried username - password flow using Admin credentials and it worked fine. When I changed the endpoint with community url and used credentials of an active community user, got this error : `{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "grant type not supported"
}`

Comment: It worked. Thank you Samuel for this infomation.  Web Server Auth Flow is working perfect with communities. But Username-Password flow will not work in this case.